# Extracting a url from a html div class with jsoup

Tags: android

I want to extract the url from the html code and set it as a string in a text view in my app, any help on how to do it?

```
<div class = "content">
<img src="http://static.truegamer.com/uploads/1720905/2577706-june24_20140625.jpg"></a> 
</div>
```

and this is the java code

```
try {
            // Connect to the web site
            Document documentImage2 = Jsoup.connect(urls[0]).get();
            // Using Elements to get the class data
            Element img = documentImage2.select("div[class=content] img[src]").get(1);
            // Locate the src attribute
            String imgSrcImage2 = img.attr("src");

           ?????????

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: I think you could not get the img src ? right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is how to add a TextView and then set it's text to be the image source url.

Try this:

```
TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.image_src);

txtView.setText(imgSrcImage2);
```

image_src is the the id of the TextView element in your layout (xml file)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
Document documentImage2 = Jsoup.connect(urls[0]).get();
// Using Elements to get the class data
Element div = documentImage2.select("div[class=content]").get(1);
Document doc_i = Jsoup.parse(div.toString());
Elements image = doc_i.select("img");
String imgSrcImage2 = image.html();
```